# Electrical wiring confusion for three bathroom lights daisy-chained to a three-way switch

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

Not sure where to ask this question. I would like some input if possible. I had three puck lights daisy-chained on my bathroom ceiling. Because we're under construction  I had these in place temporarily to provide me with light:

[image]

Today, after making progress and after painting the ceiling I was ready to install some modern canless flush-mount lights with their own j-box you tuck in the ceiling. I didn't turn the power off at the circuit breaker box but I used  my voltage tester to make sure there was no current. I did the first two and when I got to the third one I noticed that the white white wire was cut flat (with no jacket stripping) and was not connected to the inexpensive temporary light fixture. I thought to myself, "How weird. I never not connect all white and black wires when daisy-chaining several lights that are controlled from one switch."

I shrugged it off thinking it was no big deal and proceeded to carry on. As I handled the wires I got a shocked as the wires touched each other or the metal j-box and a big pop came from the room like a gunshot went off. Luckily my circuit breaker cut the power so I only felt it in my hands.

The thing is, we had an electrician do some wiring in that room. I'm left wondering if he cut the white neutral wire to the lights when creating a three way light switch and somehow altered the wiring in the ceiling without telling me. He had no reason to since the lights were already working before he came in to do his job. But I'm wondering if he somehow changed the wiring to the lights that left that third light with power constantly on even though the light switch was turned off. We're having quite a bit of work done by a general contractor and the workers here are some of the POOREST communicators I've ever dealt with. If he changed the wiring to that third light and didn't tell me it would be in alignment with how poor they communicate with me. Like I said, I would never daisy-chain lights and not connect all black and white and ground wires. And I always use a wire jacket stripper on all the wires even if I cap them off and don't use them. So I know for certain that wire was altered by someone else.

These lights are on a three way switch. I don't know what else to mention to help get some input on what  happened but could that white wire not be connected to the one light in the ceiling yet still allow the three lights to work?

I tried to disconnect the white wire again but as it stands now I think I blew both of my three-way switches as nothing is working anymore as far as the three lights are concerned.

Addendum:

[image]
Pic above shows the three way switch on the left which does have a white wire that the electrician told me to connect. I think he said it was hot or active. I can't remember. He put a piece of blue tape on it and told me to make sure to connect it.

[image]
Second pic above shows the J-Box open and the wiring exposed. I am pretty sure I disconnected the white wire that was cut and left dangling. But I could double check with my voltage tester and see.

[image]
Third image above shows the three canless lights I am installing. The last one in back is the one dangling that gave me trouble.

Comment: Newer relay on colors. people do the weirdest thing with them. Always use your meter. The short should have not blown your 3 way switches, but it is possible.

Comment: A short circuit can occur in 3 ways. 1- Black wire (power) touches the ground. 2- Black and White touch each other. 3- You touch the Black (power) wile touching a wall or standing barefooted on tile floor. (This one would kill you (unless you have GFCI)

Comment: Long post. What was the last thing you did before the spark

Comment: I don't know which wire created the short. Since I had these lights daisy-chained I had two Romex wires disconnected from the light in the ceiling. It could have been any of those wires. But all I know that was off was that one of the white wires was clipped and not connected to the light fixture itself. So I stripped the end and connected it and now nothing is working.

Comment: Please do not do that agin. Someone could have switched the 3 way switch while you were working. Open each 3 way and test for power and if it is switching. Meanwhile check the circuit breakers. You might have GFCI there that trigered.

Comment: There are two different lights in the bathroom. One of them that I already wired up and connected weeks ago is working fine. It still has power and is part of the same three gang junction box. It's a small bathroom and I was by myself so there was no risk of someone walking in and turning it on. I would have been aware of that possibility if I were in a space with lots of people using the space.

Comment: So where is the other 3way switch (one in bathroom and the other ?? Did you check for triggered GFCI on the main panel.

Comment: I just added the pic. Somehow it got lost. See above. It should be there. The one that is not working is the one on the left. I haven't tucked them back into the wall yet. But that should help as that should allow you to see the wiring a lot better.

Comment: OK, Pic 1 shows White going into 3 way switch, that is WRONG, 3 way switches only switch the phase ( there should not be neutral there) There is usually 2 black on one side and one red on the other side.

Comment: Pic 2 is busy, but twist lock all whites together and have one going to the light. Do the same with blacks.

Comment: He told me he made the white wire a hot wire at the junction box. At the junction box the three way switch on the left controls lights on the ceiling (my issue I'm having). The three way light switch on the right controls lights above a medicine cabinet. They are both three way switches because there are two doors to enter the room. So there are switches at both doors. GFCI is separate and was not affected.

Comment: The switch on the left is for ceiling lights, The switch on the right has correct colors. If the white is Hot (wrong color) it should go in place of the red wire on the switch and red where the white was.

Comment: Like I said, the electrician told me it was hot and marked it as such. It was working fine until I tried to remove the ceiling lights. Now I'm not even sure if my light switches are blown out. I can't get the lights to work.

Comment: What was working ??? The old lights were switchable on/off.  Did the electrician connect the 3 way switch or did you ? Do you have any power on any wires in that box ? If yes describe it.